# Замените все положительные элементы списка на первый элемент

Tags: python, list

Замените все положительные элементы на первый элемент массива

```
 a = [10, -15, 3, 8, 0, 9, -6, 13, -1, 5]
    b = []

for i in a:
    if i > 0:
        b.append(10)
print(b)
```

Нужно заменить только положительные элементы.

Comment: Так вам надо заменить элементы в существующем списке или создать новый?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10, -15, 3, 8, 0, 9, -6, 13, -1, 5]
b = []

for i in a:
    if i > 0:
        b.append(a[0])
    else:
        b.append(i)

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если замечание в комментарии все-таки верно:

```py
a = [10, -15, 3, 8, 0, 9, -6, 13, -1, 5]

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    a[i] = a[0] if a[i] < 0 else a[i]
```